# Street to List of GPS Coordinates

Tags: dictionary, gps, openstreetmap

I have two GPS Coordinates, (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)... I there any free information available where I could A) retrieve the street coordinates that connects the coordinates, and B) retrieve all coordinates along the path connecting them.

So, two coordinates... what are all the gps coordinates between them and needs to be realistic to actual street paths.. Research so far has included Open Street Maps, Great Circle Calculations using bearings and Great Circle Distances.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [CloudMade's API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/routing-http-api).

> CloudMade's powerful Routing web services deliver turn-by-turn directions across multiple devices and platforms. With this flexible, easy to use web service you can:
>
> - Quickly and easily integrate vehicle, bicycle or pedestrian routing into your existing web, mobile and desktop applications
> - Build navigation applications that provide real-time, turn-by-turn routing to your users
> - Integrate with other CloudMade services to create rich interactive experience on the web, iPhone, Symbian, J2ME and beyond

Here's [CloudMade's terms of service](http://cloudmade.com/about/api-terms-and-conditions).